# Creating table with error in mysql with Storage engine 'myisam' and data directory

Tags: mysql

I tried to create a table with MyISAM as storage engine in mysql. But the query is failed to execute with following error code.

`Can't create/write to file '/Users/arun_kumar/Desktop/Test_DB_Data/Inde/myisam_data.MYI' (Errcode: 13)`

Following is the query I have used,

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`myisam_data` (
  `tee_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tee_id`)
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
CHARACTER SET utf8
DATA DIRECTORY = '/Users/arun_kumar/Desktop/Test_DB_Data/Data'
INDEX DIRECTORY = '/Users/arun_kumar/Desktop/Test_DB_Data/Inde';
```

Purpose of choosing myisam is it will support disk partition for different table, Where I need to store few tables in one disk and the remaining in another disk with in same database.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Are you sure that MySQL has rights to write to that directory?

Comment: I given all the rights to this directory

Comment: @AmitBhargava:  I given all the rights to this directory with command 'chmod a+w'  still not able to create table.

Comment: @juergend:  I tried the above query in another ubuntu machine.  It responded with same error code.

Answer (score 1):

OS error code 13 is "Permission denied".
Check if your mysql's system user has the rights to chdir() to the directories "/Users/arun_kumar/Desktop/Test_DB_Data/Inde" and "/Users/arun_kumar/Desktop/Test_DB_Data/Data". Those directories must have permissions like u+rwx,g-rwx,o-rwx ("700") and must belong to the mysql user. Any subdir should belong to the mysql user or have "+x" permission for "other"

Just to be double sure that is a permission problem, try this script that create a directory called /tmp/mysqltest and change its permissions:

```
TESTDIR="/tmp/mysqltest"
mkdir "$TESTDIR"
sudo chown `ps faxu | grep 'mysqld ' | grep -v logg | grep -v grep | cut -d' ' -f1` "$TESTDIR"
sudo chmod 700 "$TESTDIR"
```

The try the modified query:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`myisam_data` (
  `tee_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tee_id`)
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
CHARACTER SET utf8
DATA DIRECTORY = '/tmp/mysqltest'
INDEX DIRECTORY = '/tmp/mysqltest';
```

Comment: I have changed the directory permission for Test_DB_Data using (sudo chmod 700 Test_DB_Data command) And changed the DATA DIRECTORY PATH to   /Users/arun_kumar/Desktop/Test_DB_Data.  

Still facing the same problem.

CREATE TABLE `test`.`new_table` (
  `tee_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tee_id`)
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
CHARACTER SET utf8
DATA DIRECTORY = '/Users/arun_kumar/Desktop/Test_DB_Data'
INDEX DIRECTORY = '/Users/arun_kumar/Desktop/Test_DB_Data';

Comment: I thought that the MySQL having problem while creating temporary files for this table.

Comment: @Arun please check my modified Answer and please let me know if it works.

Comment: I have fixed this by configuring AppArmor

http://informationideas.com/news/2010/04/15/changing-mysql-data-directory-require-change-to-apparmor/

Thank you for your support: